# Closing and coloring areas in a radar chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code to obtain a radar chart using `ggplot2`:

```
ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=Tooth, y=Comparison, group=group)) + 
  geom_point(color = "#F8766D", size=1.5) + 
  geom_line(lty = 2) + 
  geom_area(alpha=0.2, position = position_identity(), color = "#F8766D") +
  geom_hline(aes(group=group, yintercept=0), lwd=1, lty=2, alpha=0.5) + 
  coord_polar() + 
  theme(legend.key = element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray92"))
```

And this is the resulting figure.

[image]

My questions are:

- How can I change the color of the area which is now gray? I added `color = "#F8766D"` to the `geom_area()` function, which ultimately resulted in coloring the line, but not the area.
- As you can see, the area is not totally close. So, how can I close the area between UP3 and UP4? They are placed at the top of the radar.
- As you may notice, there is no data for LI1, that's why there is not a point for this observation. This results in a gap in the area. How can I connect points from LI2 to UI1, avoiding missing data and thus closing the area?

This is the dataset, obtained using `dput()`:

```
structure(list(dataset = c(-23.8789646372585, NaN, -10.8009305417082, 
-11.8411770633881, -19.000246852629, -14.364572544966, -21.8175372410621, 
-25.4455825234135, -16.3659714913407, -24.2952691912406, -0.794961013892774, 
9.27790872080566, -20.9411764705882, -20.3132576468705, -25.1353910061732, 
-17.0200414318061), Tooth = c("UI1", "LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", 
"LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", "UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", 
"UM3", "LM3"), group = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a")), .Names = c("Comparison", 
"Tooth", "group"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("UI1", 
"LI1", "UI2", "LI2", "UC", "LC", "UP3", "LP3", "UP4", "LP4", 
"UM1", "LM1", "UM2", "LM2", "UM3", "LM3"))
```

Comment: Could you post output from `dput(dataset)`?  To change the color of your  `geom_area()` just change the `color = "#f8766D"` to  `fill = "#f8766D"`

Comment: @utubun, I just edited the question with the data using `dput()`. Hope you can help me.